# Adobe Reader breaks ALT+TAB when opening new file

Tags: adobe-reader, keyboard-navigation

When there is already one instance of Adobe Reader open with, say, `a.pdf`, and you launch another file (`b.pdf`) from, say, your browser, for a brief moment `a.pdf` is displayed while `b.pdf` is being processed before opened.

This behavior is annoying if you are an avid keyboard user because it breaks the current flow:

- if you try to ALT+TAB back to the browser, you'll face `a.pdf`, which is a relic from something you were doing thirty hours later and will come back to eventually, but wasn't planning to see again right now;
- if you quickly decide `b.pdf` isn't interesting and want to go back to the browser ASAP, you ALT+F4 out of it and suddenly, like above, you don't know why you're facing (like above).

Is there any solution for this? I just want to have Adobe Reader show me the file I'm opening. Don't need to restore any ancient previous windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible answer is to make Windows pass `AcroRd32.exe` the argument `/n` by default when opening PDF files.

This creates a new instance of Reader, ignoring the current session with the previously opened files.

The main drawback I see, however, is that if the file was already open, it will be "relaunched," instead of taking advantage of the preexisting window.